# How to overwrite a table in Access when importing data from a spreadsheet using the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet Method?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I can't figure out how to overwrite current table in Access when I import data from an Excel spreadsheet using the `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` method. The code below appends the imported data to `table1` while I want to overwrite it with the imported data.

```
    Sub AccImport()
        Dim s As Long: s = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Dim acc As New Access.Application
        acc.Visible = True
        acc.OpenCurrentDatabase "F:\dbs\myDB.accdb"
        acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
        TransferType:=acImport, _
        SpreadSheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
        TableName:="table1", _
        Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
        HasFieldNames:=True, _
        Range:="Sheet1$A1:P" & s
        acc.CloseCurrentDatabase
        acc.Quit
        Set acc = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discard the existing data from *table1* before calling `TransferSpreadsheet`:

```vb
acc.OpenCurrentDatabase "F:\dbs\myDB.accdb"
acc.CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM table1;", 128 ' dbFailOnError = 128
acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet ...
```

If the structure of the target table must change to accept new data from `TransferSpreadsheet`, you can remove the table first and allow `TransferSpreadsheet` to re-create it with the new structure.  You can execute `DROP TABLE table1;` or use the `DoCmd.DeleteObject` method to remove the table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just have two quick follow-up questions. th structure of the table will remain the same, however i have noticed that the primary keys keep on increasing (not starting from 1) everytime I execute acc.CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM table1;", 128. On the other hand removing the table totally with DROP TABLE table1, removes the primary key column all together. How can I keep the primary key with TRansferSpreadSheet

Comment: Sounds like the primary key is autonumber data type, so that is to be expected.  The easiest course of action for you is to decide you don't care whether your current set of autonumber values start from 1.  They will still be guaranteed to be distinct, which satisfies the primary key requirement.  If that is not acceptable, you must compact the db after discarding existing rows or execute an `ALTER TABLE` statement to reset the autonumber seed value to 1.